# Move the whole joomla site to a different directoy/subdomain

Tags: joomla

I am currently developing a joomla 1.5 based site in a temp subdomain (which points to a subfolder on ther sever where all joomla stuff is installed). Currently I am using plugins joomgallery an kunene 1.0.9 (legacy mode).
Once the development is done I would like to move the whole site into the root directory and delete the whole subdomain. How would this ideally be done? Can I just move the files or is there more to it? Any common pitfalls to watch out for? E.g. Are there absolute paths referenced somehwere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your configuration.php file, the base path might be defined, something like this:

```
var $live_site = 'http://temp.mysite.com/';
```

...though I think by default now, it automatically detects this value for you.

Check in the configuration of your custom components to see if they have got the paths "hardcoded" in there too.

Another thing you could do is set up a `.htaccess` file with some `RewriteRule`s so that any call to `http://temp.mysite.com` gets redirected to `http://www.mysite.com`

Comment: I might have to check the DB for absolute paths too ?

Comment: You shouldn't have to check the DB unless you entered hardcoded absolute URLs into content items.

Answer (score 0):

There is a free Joomla! extension for this called Joomlapack. Just make a backup with Joomlapack, move the backup files that was created to the new site/folder and run the script that also was created in the backup. Done! 
Joomlapack makes a complete backup on both the DB and site files so you can move your site anywhere if you wanted. Joomlapack can be found here: http://www.joomlapack.net/

Comment: will the same solution apply for joomla 1.7 as well? i have the same question above only it joomla 1.7

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to edit your configuration.php file as per [these instructions](http://kb.siteground.com/article/How_to_move_Joomla_to_another_directory.html).